# Using union on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

It gives me error when i try to join two tables.Both tables has same number of columns

Here is the error

```
failed to find conversion function from unknown to text  

select * from table1
union
select * from table 2;
```

Comment: The column types need to be the same for each table as well. It's telling you there's an `unknown` column type that it's trying to union with a `text` column type.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `UNION` columns need the same type as the same position.

use clear column name instead of `*`, Because we can't predict the number of columns after `table1` or `table2` is different.

```
select col1,col2...
from table1
union
select col1,col2...
from table2;
```